# How to access unix odbc in apache server

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, freetds, unixodbc

I am using ubuntu server 14 .I already installed freetds,unixodbc and pyodbc,if I run python program in my home folder means I can access  mssql database ,same coding not working in apache server ,php file also can't connect access to database .So please any one help me how to connect database in apache server

Comment: what errors do you get in when trying to run it via apache? Also how are you calling/initializing TDS?  Does the apache process have access to your interfaces file?

Comment: No errors are showing,and we are connecting TDS using pyodbc in python and mssql_connect() in php

Comment: I got unable to connect server error in php

Comment: with freetds there is a `freetds.conf` file that the libraries normally access, where your servers are defined. Check the permissions on that file, and make sure that the user that your scripts run under on the webserver has access to read the file.  also yo should be able to enable debugging to see where it is failing